# What do these logcat messages mean "DurationMetric 621770508523184581 dropping data for what dimension key (10)0x2010101->11019[I] (10)0x30..."

Tags: android

I have started seeing the following messages in my current Android application `logcat` output

```
2022-12-22 14:44:07.284 1349-1355 statsd statsd E DurationMetric 621770508523184581 dropping data for what dimension key (10)0x2010101->11019[I] (10)0x30000->*job*/com.my.app/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService#28[S]
```

I have no idea what is causing them or what the message signifies

should I be concerned something is wrong with my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google found this page when searching for "android statsd".

https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/modular-system/statsd

> a native service that runs in the background collecting metrics

I don't think you need to be concerned. - unless that background task is unexpected when running the `com.my.app` package on your device.